# Truncating head of a UILabel with 2 lines

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIlabel which has numberOfLines as 2
and lineBreakMode = Truncate Head

But when i run it 
Instead of truncating head on first line like

```
    ...1st Line Content
    2nd Line Content
```

It truncates like

```
    1st Line Content 
    ...2nd Line Content
```

How do i truncate the head of the label in the first line itself?

Comment: @Joe : I need it to truncate like the first block.

Comment: I had similar problem when I wanted to display only last 2 lines of the text in `UILabel`. I ended up using `UITextView` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code tested in `Swift 3`

```
   let text = "Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! "
    let attString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = .left 
    paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 0
    paragraphStyle.headIndent = 40 // set any vallue
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingHead
    attString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attString.length))
    attString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 25)!, range: NSMakeRange(0, attString.length))
    label.attributedText = attString // label is your UILabel
    label.numberOfLines = 2
```

Output 1:

[image]

```
    paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 40 // set any vallue
    paragraphStyle.headIndent = 0
```

Output 2:

[image]

**Updated:** You can achieve by combain two attribute string

```
    let dotAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 25)]
    let textAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 25)]

    let dotString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: ". . . ", attributes: dotAttributes)
    let textString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!", attributes: textAttributes)

    let totalString = NSMutableAttributedString()
    totalString.append(dotString)
    totalString.append(textString) 

    label.numberOfLines = 2
    label.attributedText = totalString
```

**Note:** You can use paragraphStyle(headIndent) to create left  margin.

```
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = .left 
    paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 5
    paragraphStyle.headIndent = 5 // set any vallue
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingHead
    totalString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, totalString.length))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I need it truncated with the dots. Not with space
The feature that you get when you truncate the tail.